# How to vertically align the group names in Timeline

Tags: javascript, chap-links-library, vis.js

How to vertically align (*middle*) the group names (IDs) using the visjs Timeline.

[visjs.org](http://visjs.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible as the height of a group is determined from the max of the label height and the (stacked) items height.

If your groups have a known height though (like if you don't use stacking of items), you could just give the CSS of the group labels a matching fixed height, and add CSS to align the text to the middle.